# Требуется ли в данном случае постановка запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

*Рождённый бегать убежит.* И почему?

Answer (score 2):

***Рождённый бегать — убежит.***

Постановка интонационного тире возможна, но это зависит от структуры предложения.

Окончательное решение определяется **по контексту**, например:

(1) *Рожденный ползать останется на своем месте, рождённый бегать — убежит* (тире в параллельной  структуре).

(2) *Рожденный бегать убежит, сколько его ни держи* (нет паузы и тире).

Answer (score 2):

*Рождённый бегать — убежит.*

На мой взгляд, тире здесь необходимо по *смысловым* причинам. Возможная двусмысленность: *с чего это рождённый "убежит бегать"?*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Между какими словами Вы могли её помыслить?

Разбить подлежащее "рождённый бегать" с трудом представляется возможным, поставить же запятую между подлежащим и сказуемым также немыслимо.